# Return a View from external Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to choose between multiple clients before returning a view in ASP.NET Core MVC.

So let there be a HomeController with the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public virtual IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now I have multiple clients, and I want to decide what view will be returned. But not at this place, so I want to write it in another file.

So my question is, is there something possible like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public virtual IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewChooser vc = new ViewChooser();
        return vc.GetNextView();
    }
}

public class ViewChooser
{
    public IActionResult GetNextView()
    {
        // do some stuff and then..
        return View("aaaa");
    }
}
```

The class "ViewChooser" does not inherit from Controller, so I can't just write *return View()*.

The reason why I want this to work like this is because I want to choose between multiple workflows without changing the URL. (Otherwise areas would be a possible solution for my problem.)
So if customer A calls *www.myserver.com/function1* he get another functionality and view as customer B.

Any ideas? Or am I far away from the solution?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have `ViewChooser` inherit from `Controller`.  It is, after all, trying to return a view which is something a controller does.

Alternatively, just have `ViewChooser` return the *name* of the view:

```
public class ViewChooser
{
    public string GetNextView()
    {
        // do some stuff and then..
        return "aaaa";
    }
}
```

And your controller can use that for its view selection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public virtual IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewChooser vc = new ViewChooser();
        return View(vc.GetNextView());
    }
}
```

This would mean that `GetNextView()` must always return a valid named view, never another kind of `IActionResult`.  But would decouple the `ViewChooser` from the MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of clients say "5 clients" then you can create 5 different ActionResult Methods which will return 5 different views. Afterwards you can create a custom attribute where you will write the logic for fetching the client information. You can put this custom attribute over each ActionResult method.